# How to create ggplot2 100% horizontal stacked bar chart with counts shown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I am handling some data from a survey regarding feeling about several factors related to workplace culture. It is currently in a longform `tibble` called `work_culture_data` like this:

```
> print(work_culture_data, n = 21)
# A tibble: 140 × 3
   Response_ID Factor                    Level    
         <int> <fct>                     <fct>    
 1           6 Level_support_colleagues  low      
 2           6 Level_support_community   low      
 3           6 Level_career_prospects    low      
 4           6 Level_career_satisfaction high     
 5           6 Level_career_impact       low      
 6           6 Level_collaboration       high     
 7           6 Level_assessment_fairness high     
 8           7 Level_support_colleagues  high     
 9           7 Level_support_community   high     
10           7 Level_career_prospects    very high
11           7 Level_career_satisfaction high     
12           7 Level_career_impact       high     
13           7 Level_collaboration       high     
14           7 Level_assessment_fairness high     
15           8 Level_support_colleagues  high     
16           8 Level_support_community   low      
17           8 Level_career_prospects    very low 
18           8 Level_career_satisfaction high     
19           8 Level_career_impact       high     
20           8 Level_collaboration       low      
21           8 Level_assessment_fairness low      
# … with 119 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Which can be recreated with this `dput()` output:

```
structure(list(Response_ID = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), 
    Factor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), levels = c("Level_support_colleagues", 
    "Level_support_community", "Level_career_prospects", "Level_career_satisfaction", 
    "Level_career_impact", "Level_collaboration", "Level_assessment_fairness"
    ), class = "factor"), Level = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L), levels = c("very low", "low", "high", "very high"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-140L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The actual dataset has 2000+ rows representing 400+ responses, and `work_culture_data` here is a subset of 20 survey responses (20 unique `Response_ID`s) where they rate (`Level` factor variable from "very low" to "very high") seven factors (`Factor` factor variable) about their workplace culture. For example, respondent number `6` thinks their `Level_career_prospects` is `low`.

Based on `work_culture_data`, I'd like to create a 100% stacked bar chart with `ggplot2` with the following features:

1. The `Factors` are renamed in the final graph, such as from `Level_career_prospects` to "Career prospects". This will be the vertical axis.
2. The stacked bars are horizontal where I can specify its component colors.
3. There will be seven stacked bars altogether, each representing one of each `Factor`.
4. The stacked bars are made of the ***proportion*** of respondents who chose `Level`s in order from "very low" to "very high" (total four levels). Each segment of a stacked bar represents one of `Level`s. Each stacked bar adds to 100%.
5. The horizontal axis has three labelled breaks: 0%, 50%, and 100% from left to right.
6. The *order* of the stacked bars goes from the one with highest proportion of "very low" to least, from top to bottom.
7. Ideally, I'd like the *count* of responses for each segment of the stacked bars shown.

I tried to create this plot starting with this line:

```
work_culture_fig <- ggplot(work_culture_data, aes(y = Factor, x = Level)) + 
    geom_col()
```

However, it gave me this output which baffles me:

[image: failed 100% stacked bar plot]

I don't know where to go from here and am very confused... Should the `tibble` data frame be widened first?

What did I did wrong? And **how do I achieve 1~7 above in the final figure?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Ive changed outside of ggplot the order of Factor. You could obviously keep the original features by adding new columns instead of mutating your existing ones.
Also I changes instead of using four manual colors to a set pallete. R has really nice coloring options and you can make yourself familiar with them as time progresses. If you prefer manual coloring, use the line from the previous answer.

```
# Start by removing the "levels" from each word
t <- work_cultur_data$Factor
t <- gsub("Level_([a-z])", " \\U\\1", t, perl=TRUE)
t<- gsub("^([a-z])", "\\U\\1", t, perl=TRUE)
t <- str_to_title(str_trim( gsub("_", " ", t) )) 
work_cultur_data$Factor <- t

# Change levels
l <- work_cultur_data$Level
l <-  fct_relevel(work_cultur_data$Level,c("very high","high","low","very low"))
work_cultur_data$Level <- l


# Sort Factor by prop of Very low (Level)
arng_by <- work_cultur_data %>%
  filter(Level=="very low") %>% 
  group_by(Factor,Level) %>% 
  summarize(prop=n()) %>% arrange(prop) %>% pull(Factor)

f <- work_cultur_data$Factor
f <- fct_relevel(work_cultur_data$Factor,arng_by)
work_cultur_data$Factor <- f
# Plot
work_cultur_data %>%   group_by(Factor,Level) %>% summarize(prop=n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y=Factor,x=prop,fill=Level))+
  geom_col(position="fill")+labs(fill="")+ylab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure if i understod correctly..

```
# Start by removing the "levels" from each word
t <- work_cultur_data$Factor
work_cultur_data$Factor <- gsub("Level_([a-z])", " \\U\\1", t, perl=TRUE)
work_cultur_data$Factor<- gsub("^([a-z])", "\\U\\1", t, perl=TRUE)
work_cultur_data$Factor <- str_to_title(str_trim( gsub("_", " ", t) )) 
work_cultur_data$Factor <- t

# Change levels
l <- work_cultur_data$Level
l <-  fct_relevel(work_cultur_data$Level,c("very high","high","low","very low"))
work_cultur_data$Level <- l

# Plot
work_cultur_data %>%   
    ggplot(aes(x=Factor,fill=Level))+
  geom_bar()+labs(fill="")+ylab("")+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

##### Changed the code to make it as percentage. I also corrected for the axis and made it more clear that it should be porportional.

[image]

```
# Plot
work_cultur_data %>%   group_by(Factor,Level) %>% summarize(prop=n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y=Factor,x=prop,fill=Level))+
  geom_col(position="fill")+labs(fill="")+ylab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

##### To change colors manualy:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=sample(colors(),
                                  length(unique(work_cultur_data$Level))))
```

This is just a fancy shamncy way to sample different colors each time depending on how many unique levels you got in your `fill` argument. You could just specify the `values` to be `c("red","#1CD317",colors()[444],"deeppink")` - just different types of colors (either HEX code, a name, an index from all possible named colors or my favorite: DEEP PINK!

Comment: if you wanna flip x and y, actually change x and y in aes, and don't use coord_flip

Comment: Thank you @RYann that is close! But I'd like the vertical axis in your plot to represent *proportions* instead of *count*. And do you have any suggestions for the other things I listed in 1-7?

Comment: Isnt it already proportional? I edited my solution to include a bit of rough regex but it is not pretty (i suck at regex). and ofcourse @tjebo is correct, I shouldve just change the 'aes'.

Comment: Definitely very close now, and like I asked in the question: Is there a way to specify colors? And can the vertical axis show marks for 0%, 50%, and 100%? Many thanks!

Comment: Sure. refer to my edited answer

Comment: Sorry almost there. There are still a few things from the original question: 

2. Can colors be manually specified for each segment of the bars?

6. Can the stacked bars be ordered from top to bottom by the `Factor` with the highest proportion of "very low" (or any other `Level`) on top?

Comment: I edited the color option. about the levels, I changed it at the beginning. if you want to change it to a different order just edit the section where i specified "Change levels". the relevant command is fct_relevel.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I wasn't clear regarding `fct_relevel`. I don't need to change the order of "very low" to "very high". What I want is for the `Factor` with the highest proportion of "very low" to be the top stack (i.e. "Career Prospects"), and the `Factor` with the lowest proportion of "very low" to be the bottom stack. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think we're getting there (New answer below)