# How to create separate levels order for the same factor in facetted ggplot2 bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a `tibble` data frame called `research_culture_by_career` like this:

```
> print(n = 21, research_culture_by_career)
# A tibble: 2,842 × 4
   Response_ID Career_stage      Factor                       Level    
         <int> <chr>             <fct>                        <fct>    
 1           1 more than 5 years Support from colleagues      high     
 2           1 more than 5 years Support from community       low      
 3           1 more than 5 years Career prospects             high     
 4           1 more than 5 years Career satisfaction          high     
 5           1 more than 5 years Research impact              low      
 6           1 more than 5 years Collaboration between groups high     
 7           1 more than 5 years Fairness of assessment       very low 
 8           2 more than 5 years Support from colleagues      very high
 9           2 more than 5 years Support from community       very low 
10           2 more than 5 years Career prospects             very low 
11           2 more than 5 years Career satisfaction          very high
12           2 more than 5 years Research impact              very low 
13           2 more than 5 years Collaboration between groups high     
14           2 more than 5 years Fairness of assessment       low      
15           3 less than 5 years Support from colleagues      high     
16           3 less than 5 years Support from community       high     
17           3 less than 5 years Career prospects             high     
18           3 less than 5 years Career satisfaction          high     
19           3 less than 5 years Research impact              high     
20           3 less than 5 years Collaboration between groups high     
21           3 less than 5 years Fairness of assessment       high     
# … with 2,821 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This data set contains 2000+ survey responses (each response has a unique `Response_ID`) with questions on the `Career_stage` of a worker (whether they have worked for more or less than 5 years), their `Level` of feeling (from "very low" to "very high") about a `Factor` of their work (e.g. "Support from colleagues").

It can be reproduced via the complete data set I've uploaded here as a CSV file (though the factors need to be re-created):

```
research_culture_by_career <- read_csv(file = "https://0x0.st/HrTp.csv", 
                                       col_types = c("i", "c", "f", "f"))
```

Right now, I use the following code to plot these responses into a horizontal 100% stacked bar plot with `ggplot2`:

```
# Order the eventual display of factors by the proportion of "very low"
research_culture_by_career$"Factor" <- as.character(research_culture_by_career$"Factor")
prop_order <- research_culture_by_career %>%
    filter(`Level` == "very low") %>%
    group_by(`Factor`, `Level`) %>%
    # Get number of responses (`votes`) for "very low" for each factor.
    summarise(votes = n()) %>%
    arrange(votes) %>%
    # Keep just the `Factor` variable as a list of factors, which is now ordered
    # by "very low" and can be used to order them in a visualisation.
    pull(`Factor`)
# Relevel the `Factor`s by this new ordering.
research_culture_by_career$"Factor" <- fct_relevel(research_culture_by_career$"Factor", prop_order)
rm(prop_order)

# Create 100% stacked bar plot
research_culture_by_career_fig <- research_culture_by_career %>%
    group_by(`Factor`, `Level`) %>%
    summarise(prop = n()) %>% # I.e. number of responses for each level
    ggplot(aes(x = `prop`, y = `Factor`, fill = `Level`)) +
    geom_col(position = "fill") +
    # facet_wrap(~`Career_stage`) +
    labs(x = "Proportion of responses", y = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1.0), labels = scales::percent) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL, nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
research_culture_by_career_fig
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image: 100% stacked bar plot]

**Important note:** Observe that this chunk of code begins with setting the *order* of the `Level`s so that the order of `Factor`s in the final plot is in descending order of `Level` (e.g. "Career prospects" has the highest proportion of "very low" responses, so it is on top).

I want to facet this plot by `Career_stage`, so I tried this code:

```
research_culture_by_career_fig <- research_culture_by_career %>%
    group_by(`Career_stage`, `Factor`, `Level`) %>%
    summarise(prop = n()) %>% # I.e. number of responses for each level
    ggplot(aes(x = `prop`, y = `Factor`, fill = `Level`)) +
    geom_col(position = "fill") +
    facet_wrap(~`Career_stage`) +
    labs(x = "Proportion of responses", y = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1.0), labels = scales::percent) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL, nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
research_culture_by_career_fig
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image: 100% stacked bar plot with facets]

The problem is that the *order* of the `Factor`s is not separate for the two facets. This is especially clear on the left for the "less than 5 years" facet where the stacked bars are *not* in descending order of "very low" `Level`. In other words:

**How do I set the order of the `Factor` variable by decreasing proportion of "very low" `Level`s, *with different orders* depending on `Career_stage` facets in this plot?**

P.S. Context: This is a follow up to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75414814/186904).

Comment: Are you looking for 2 different x- axis?  One order for <5 year and different order for >5 years?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I want a different order for the factors (like "Career prospects" or "Career satisfaction") for <5 years and >5 years. The order would be based on descending order of "very low" for <5 years and >5 years. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I believe the most likely option is to split your data into the two different groups and plot them separately.